# counting events given a period of time in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I want to plot the number of events (e.g., crimes) every year in a population of agents. This isn't counting the population in a state using a statechart, but an event that I recorded on the field "action" of a transition with rate *x* (e.g., `crime = crime + 1;`). So, an agent might have committed 5 crimes, another one 7, and so on, over a year.

I tried resetting the crime variable (`crime = 0;`) every year, but the plot goes from zero to some number, again to 0, jumping to another number again, and so on...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Easy. I just have to set the recurrence time of the plot to 0.999 year instead of 1 year.